# How to start SVM training on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have a set of facial features that i have obtained and would like to classify using SVM. I intend to use libsvm package and use MATLAB to carry out the training.I have already read up on SVM by watching the Stanford lecture. But I am not sure how to use libsvm to start.. Need some guidance...

Comment: What is the part that you did not understand in the matlab/readme?

Comment: how come there is both .c files as well as .m files together under the matlab folder?

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In matlab you can link your matlab code with some programs implemented in c. This a called a [mex-file](http://www.mathworks.fr/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html).

However you need to compile them, to make it work.

You can read the readme file to know how to compile them:

> ## Installation
>
> On Unix systems, we recommend using GNU g++ as your compiler and type
>   'make' to build 'svmtrain.mexglx' and 'svmpredict.mexglx'. Note that
>   we assume your MATLAB is installed in '/usr/local/matlab', if not,
>   please change MATLABDIR in Makefile.
>
> Example:
>           linux> make
>
> To use Octave, type 'make octave':
>
> Example:  linux> make octave
>
> On Windows systems, pre-built binary files are already in the
>   directory  `..\windows', so no need to conduct installation. Now we
>   include both 32bit binary files and 64bit binary files, but in future
>   releases, we  will provide binary files only for 64bit MATLAB on
>   Windows. If you have  modified the sources and would like to re-build
>   the package, type  'mex -setup' in MATLAB to choose a compiler for mex
>   first. Then type  'make' to start the installation.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>     matlab> mex -setup
> ```
>
> (ps: MATLAB will show the following messages to setup default compiler.)
>      Please choose your compiler for building external interface (MEX) files: 
>      Would you like mex to locate installed compilers [y]/n? y
>      Select a compiler: 
>     [1](http://www.mathworks.fr/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html) Microsoft Visual C/C++ version 7.1 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 
>           [0] None 
>           Compiler: 1
>           Please verify your choices: 
>           Compiler: Microsoft Visual C/C++ 7.1 
>           Location: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 
>           Are these correct?([y]/n): y
>
> ```
>     matlab> make
> ```
>
> For list of supported/compatible compilers for MATLAB, please check
>   the following page:
>
> http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

Comment: is that all u need to start SVM?

Comment: after that you can run the sample code provided in the remaining of the README

Comment: Try to install Microsoft Visual Studio Express Edition, it will install lcc. Use that as a compiler for mex.

Comment: Ok, if you don't manaage to compile it. You should try to copy the precompiled version.... it's in libsvm-3.1/windows/ ... copy all of that in the same directory than your .m files. And try again

Comment: copy to the same folder as the m files you mean?

Comment: I get this error :Could not find the compiler "cl" on the DOS path. 
         Use mex -setup to configure your environment properly.

Comment: Sorry, I guess, you'll have to work alone on that. I have a lot of work to do. Just the last tips: 1) this error is for sure because you gave wrong arguments after a mex -setup. 2) copy the files in libsvm-3.1/windows/ to libsvm-3.1/matlab and then go to matlab to the directory libsvm-3.1/matlab/ and then run "svmtrain".